# Is the problem wrongly framed$?$ If not, then find $f(\sqrt3)$

Tags: calculus, functions

> If $f(x)$ be a continuous function $\forall x$ and satisfies $$x^2+(f(x)-2)x-2\sqrt3+3-\sqrt3f(x)=0$$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ Then find the value of $f(\sqrt3)$.

From the relation given, I discovered that $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-2x+3-2\sqrt3}{\sqrt3-x}$$ So according to it, $f(x)$ isn't defined at $x=\sqrt3$. So the function is discontinuous. But it contradicts the original statement of the problem.

Is the problem wrongly framed or there is something advance that I don't know$?$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

The problem is now solved. There was a typo in the original question (the place from where I picked up the question ).

Comment: This is the complete question. If anyone wonders that is there something after *continuous function $\forall x$*, there was just this in the problem... nothing else written

Comment: Are you sure you have the question correctly?
By substituting x= sqrt(3) in the original equality you get a contradiction. I suspect you're missing negative signs. Also, that expression only holds whenever $x \neq \sqrt{3}$, as you arrive at it using a division by $x-\sqrt{3}$, so you could always define it at $x=\sqrt{3}$ as its limits (so that it's continuous). However in this case, the limit DNE.

Comment: @TC159 the question is just this...even I think that there is something Missing

Comment: My guess is there is a typo in the problem, and ${}-2\sqrt3+3$ should have been ${}+2\sqrt3-3$. Then I think the problem would make sense. That's just a guess, of course.

Comment: @DavidK you're genius...when I did the question again with the edit you suggested...and guess what I got the answer that is given as the solution

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I suggest you email your tutor or wait until the next time you seem them to inform them of the mistake. If you're self studying maybe add an edit and move on